# How to print hash values using perl CGI

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm new to perl CGI and trying to print hash data to html using perl CGI. Below is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI ':standard';
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);

our %dashboard_data;
my $q = new CGI;

################################################################################
## Read the dashboard_data file
require "partition_tsv_dashboard.pl";

print   $q->header,
        $q->start_html('Top Level TSV Dashboards'),
        $q->h1('Top Level TSV Dashboards'),
foreach my $model (sort keys %{$dashboard_data{'project'}}){
        $q->h2("Model: $model"),
}
        $q->end_html;
```

The partition_tsv_dashboard.pl is the nested hash. Contains below data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$dashboard_data {'project'} {'model1'} {'P00'} {'TSV-193'} {'COMP_0_P00'} = '';
$dashboard_data {'project'} {'model2'} {'P00'} {'TSV-001'} {'COMP_0_P00'} = '';
$dashboard_data {'project'} {'model3'} {'P00'} {'TSV-001'} {'COMP_0_P00'} = '';
$dashboard_data {'project'} {'model4'} {'P00'} {'TSV-001'} {'COMP_0_P00'} = '';
$dashboard_data {'project'} {'model5'} {'P00'} {'TSV-001'} {'COMP_0_P00'} = '';

1;
```

I'm getting below error when I try execute the CGI program. How do I map the a hash values to CGI object? Can someone help me with this.

Output.

```
Software error:
syntax error at /web/keystone/cgi-bin/tsv_dashboard.pl line 26, near "$model ("
Execution of /web/keystone/cgi-bin/tsv_dashboard.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: I don't think you can have a for loop within another list. Try split the print statement up instead

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a `for` loop inside the argument list of the `print` statement. Instead try split it up like this.

```
print   $q->header,
        $q->start_html('Top Level TSV Dashboards'),
        $q->h1('Top Level TSV Dashboards');

foreach my $model (sort keys %{$dashboard_data{'project'}}){
        print $q->h2("Model: $model");
}
print   $q->end_html;
```

Comment: HTML injection bug in the h2 line

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It would depend on what the script `partition_tsv_dashboard.pl` does right? Since it is responsible for populating the `%dashboard_data` hash. If the script does not use user input to populate the hash, it cannot be the source of a HTML injection bug as I understand it..

Comment: I find it very unlikely that `%dashboard_data` contains HTML rather than plain text.

Answer (score 1):

The prior answer from @Håkon Hægland is likely the best answer, but you could use `map` to achieve a similar result.

```perl
use CGI ':standard';

my $q = new CGI;

my @a = ("blah", "wooble");

print $q->h1("things"), "\n",
      (map { $q->h2($_) } @a), "\n",
      $q->br, "\n";
```

To get this output:

```
% perl test.pl
<h1>things</h1>
<h2>blah</h2><h2>wooble</h2>
<br />
```